# Removal feature not enabled, how do I add required permissions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, trello

I am using this for the API: https://github.com/norberteder/trello

When i make a request to :`DELETE /1/organizations/[idOrg or name]/members/[idMember]/all`

It shows an error message saying

> removal feature not enabled

im guessting it has to do with me not having the required permission of 'removal' below is the link for that.

https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/organization#delete-1-organizations-idorg-or-name-members-idmember-all

But how would I be able to add that permission? where would i do that?

Comment: There is a note on the delete *This is an experimental resource and may change at any time without notice.*

Comment: Erm i dont see it: https://i.gyazo.com/08b84e8298051ba83a8f0726c4ca81f6.png

Answer (score 0):

This is a route that is only available to organizations that have [Business Class](https://trello.com/business-class) enabled.

The documentation you referenced includes:

> The team must be upgraded to Business Class in order for this option
>   to be enabled.